# How to test ClipboardOwner#lostOwnership()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, clipboard, mockito

There is 'Owner' class. It implements ClipboardOwner. A Owner works in separated thread and listens the system clipboard. The Owner does some work when clipboard's content changed.
I wrote unit test for Owner. I lunched Owner's thread and change clipboard's content. The lostOwnership() was invoked (I saw message in console). But the spy don't note it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;

class Owner extends Thread implements ClipboardOwner {
    public Owner(){
        super("Owner");
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        regainOwnership(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard());
        while (true) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard cb, Transferable t) {
        //process the change of clipboard's content
        regainOwnership(cb);
    }

    private void regainOwnership(Clipboard cb) {
        cb.setContents(cb.getContents(null), this);
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class OwnerTest {
    @Test
    public void testLostOwnership() throws Exception {
        Owner owner = spy(new Owner());
        Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        Transferable t = mock(Transferable.class);
        ClipboardOwner newOwner = mock(ClipboardOwner.class);
        cb.setContents(t, newOwner);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        verify(owner).lostOwnership(cb, t);//test error: Wanted but not invoked
    }
}
```

Problem: test fails because the spy don't note that Owner#lostOwnership() was invoke.

What do you think about this?
Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you are testing the AWT classes?  I suspect this has been done already.

Comment: I wish test calling "//process the change of clipboard's content".

Comment: I also have same query. What did you do to test this scenario?